# How to test a component rendering child component when the local useState is changes in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to Jest/Enzyme and I have the below component:

```
App.js:
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import ChildA from './Children/ChildA';
import ChildB from './Children/ChildB';

export const app = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return(
       <Fragment>
           {open ? <ChildA /> : <ChildB />}
       </Fragment>
    );
}
```

I have checked in the Enzyme docs and have seen a method 'setState' but it cannot be used for my component testing as 'setState' can only by used on Class component and not on functional component.
Can anyone please help me if there is any other way to test this using JEST+Enzyme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No...you cannot test this. Unit testing is for functionality testing. What you are trying to test is an implementation detail.

Comment: This makes sense to me now. Many Thanks! :)